# Can we define recursive definitions in Coq?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coqide

I know Coq allows to define mutually recursive inductive types. But is there a way to write the recursive definitions in Coq?

For example, I want to write a definition as:

`Definition myDefinition A := forall B C, (myDefinition B) \/ (A = C).`

Important part in above definition is ***myDefinition B***, which is recursively calling the same definition on another argument. Is it possible to do this in Coq?

Comment: Do you intend `A` to be a piece of data (like a number or a string), if that is the case, then recursion is strictly restricted by the inductive structure of the datatype.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Fixpoint` instead of `Definition`. I encourage you to look at the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/core/inductive.html?highlight=fixpoint#top-level-recursive-functions) if you want to know more about them.

```
Fixpoint myDefinition A := 
  forall B C, (myDefinition B) \/ (A = C).
```

Note that something like the above wouldn't be accepted as terminating by Coq and hence as a valid definition. Once again, the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/core/inductive.html?highlight=fixpoint#top-level-recursive-functions) should explain what you can and can't do with examples.

---

**Edit**

If you definition is supposed to be a type, then you can also define it as an inductive type.

```
Inductive myDefinition (A : Prop) : Prop :=
| myDef : forall B C, (myDefinition B) \/ (A = C) -> myDefinition A.
```

Here we say that to build a proof of `myDefinition A` it is sufficient to prove `forall B C, (myDefinition B) \/ (A = C)`. Which is what you wanted.
You will probably have a hard time proving it however, but perhaps your concrete case is different.

Comment: In my use case, definition depends upon itself. I think one way is to split the definition into two and proceed with mutually dependent inductive types.

Comment: I have added another way using inductive types to my answer.